# Cordova android class not found

Tags: android, cordova, salesforce

I'm trying to add a cordova plugin to a salesforce mobile android app. By default, the salesforce app uses the SalesforceSDK project as a library. This project already contains several cordova plugins listed in its config.xml file, however, when I try to add a plugin and  config.xml file to my own project in the same way, cordova fails to initialise, citing 'Class not found' as the reason.

I've looked around to see what the structure should look like then to make it find the class, but every result I find shows a different way of setting up the config file, or adding a plugin.xml file somewhere, and nothing has worked so far because I just can't figure out how to do it properly.

Currently I only have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugins>
    <plugin name="OpenAppPlugin" value="com.dev.testapp.OpenAppPlugin"/>    
</plugins>
```

in my config file, because all the cordova guide says is to add that line.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had to copy the entire config.xml containing all the plugins to my own project and add the line to that.